# Strange behaviour when trying to implement twisted deferredlist

Tags: python, asynchronous, twisted

I'm new to twisted and trying to build a simple POC, however I keep getting the following error.

```
running
[]
running
[]
running
[]
running
[]
running
[]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./poc.py", line 23, in <module>
    dl = defer.DeferredList([tasks])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 820, in __init__
    deferred.addCallbacks(self._cbDeferred, self._cbDeferred,
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'addCallbacks'
```

I have been reading through the relevant twisted documentation and guides and can't seem to work out what I'm doing wrong. Does anybody know what is causing this exception?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from twisted.internet import defer

def task_to_run(data):
  print 'running'
  print data

def finished(res):
  print 'finished', res

tasks = []

for x in range(0,5):
  d = defer.Deferred()      
  d.addCallback(task_to_run)
  tasks.append(d)

dl = defer.DeferredList([tasks])
dl.addCallback(finished)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that `task_to_run` really is something that is running async, then @Elisha was pointing you at the issue (your example code lists the list and it shouldn't).  So runnable code looks like:

```python
#!/usr/bin/env python
from twisted.internet import defer

def task_to_run(data):
  print 'running'
  print data

def finished(res):
  print 'finished', res

tasks = []

for x in range(0,5):
  d = defer.Deferred()      
  d.addCallback(task_to_run)
  d.callback("blah - " + str(x)) # Fire them as I make them
  tasks.append(d)

dl = defer.DeferredList(tasks)

dl.addCallback(finished)
```

With output of:

```
% ./deferredList.py
running
blah - 0
running
blah - 1
running
blah - 2
running
blah - 3
running
blah - 4
finished [(True, None), (True, None), (True, None), (True, None), (True, None)]
```

BTW very nice docs on DeferredLists are at: [Deferred Reference](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/13.0.0/core/howto/defer.html#auto8)

---

But if the tasks aren't actually running async then you really could just make one defer queue:

```python
#!/usr/bin/env python
from twisted.internet import defer

def task_to_run(data):
  print 'running'
  print data
  return data

def finished(res):
  print 'finished', res

d = defer.Deferred()      

for x in range(0,5):
  d.addCallback(task_to_run)

d.addCallback(finished) 

d.callback("blah") # Fire the deferred
```

Runs as:

```
% ./deferred.py
running
blah
running
blah
running
blah
running
blah
running
blah
finished blah
```

Comment: BTW, the reason I suspect your `task_to_run` may not be async is because any async output from the tasks would come **after** the exception you were getting. If when you run your current code it shows the tasks completing before the exception, then `DeferredList` isn't helping you (I.E. your in the [What Deferreds don't do](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/12.3.0/core/howto/gendefer.html#auto2) trap.

Answer (score 3):

`tasks` is a list. and you pass it to `DeferredList` inside another list. (`[tasks]`)
I think you need to change the line:

```
dl = defer.DeferredList([tasks])
```

to this one:

```
dl = defer.DeferredList(tasks)
```

Comment: Hey thanks dude but that was just a typo (I actually ninja edited it a couple of minutes before you posted). Unfortunately the issue still exists.

Comment: you still pass list of lists instead of list of `deferred` objects.    

I've edited my answer to remove the part that related to your typo.