# How to catch unhandled error in Deferred originating from reactor.stop()

Tags: python, asynchronous, twisted

I am new to twisted and having trouble with the following script.

When I run the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from twisted.internet import defer
from twisted.web.client import getPage, reactor

def success(results):
  print 'success'

def error(results):
  print 'error'
  return results

def finished(results):
  print 'finished'
  reactor.stop()

tasks = []

d = getPage('thiswontwork').addCallback(success).addErrback(error)
tasks.append(d)

dl = defer.DeferredList(tasks)
dl.addCallback(finished)

reactor.run()
```

I get the following output:

```
error
finished
Unhandled error in Deferred:
Unhandled Error
Traceback (most recent call last):
Failure: twisted.internet.error.ConnectionRefusedError: Connection was refused by other side: 61: Connection refused.
```

My question is why am I getting an unhandled error when I seem to have caught the error with my error callback?

Comment: have a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23321429/strange-behaviour-when-trying-to-implement-twisted-deferredlist

Comment: @PadraicCunningham, this is fundamentally a different question then the one you referenced (see my answer)

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that in your `error` def you return `result` which, given it was called by an error back is a `Failure` object, and returning a `Failure` object is one of the two criteria for re-raising the error state.  See the following blurb from [krondo's twisted intro - part 9](http://krondo.com/blog/?p=1825):

> Now, in synchronous code we can “re-raise” an exception using the raise keyword without any arguments. Doing so raises the original exception we were handling and allows us to take some action on an error without completely handling it. It turns out we can do the same thing in an errback. A deferred will consider a callback/errback to have failed if:
>
> - The callback/errback raises any kind of exception, or
> - The callback/errback returns a Failure object.
>
> Since an errback’s first argument is always a Failure, an errback can “re-raise” the exception by returning its first argument, after performing whatever action it wants to take.

Yup, just tried it, if you change:

```
def error(results):
  print 'error'
  return results
```

to

```
def error(results):
  print 'error'
  return
```

You won't re-raise the error state, so it won't percolate back to the reactor, and won't cause the traceback thats annoying you.

P.S. I can't recommend [krondo's twisted introduction](http://krondo.com/blog/?p=1209) enough! It may be really long but if you can get through it, you really will be able to produce code in twisted and these sort of behaviors won't be a mystery.

P.P.S I see you have previous SO question ([Python DeferredList callback reporting success when deferreds raise error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23351538/python-deferredlist-callback-reporting-success-when-deferreds-raise-error)) about deferred's that might be the reason you built the code this way.  I think you may have a fundamental misunderstanding about the return-value/callback-value of def's involved in deferreds (particularly errbacks). Check out [part 9](http://krondo.com/blog/?p=1825) (though you might have to backup [part 7](http://krondo.com/blog/?p=1682) or even earlier to track it) of krondo's, it really should help clear things up.

Comment: I took a shot at explain deferreds here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23451877/3334178